# Find MySQL Data Transfer

Tags: mysql

Looking into using Amazon's RDS offering announced this week.  In doing cost analysis, I'd like to see what our current data transfer in/out in.  We have a dedicated server running Apache & MySQL 4.1.22.  `SHOW STATUS`has a Bytes_recieved and Bytes_sent variable.  Just divide that by the server's uptime and work from there, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bytes_received` or `Bytes_sent` divided by `Uptime` is the only way to pull the information from MySQL itself. You need to bear in mind that it will (obviously) be averaged over the total uptime period.

So if the server hasn't been up for very long then it may not have experienced it's true peak/trough usage. Likewise if it has been up for a long time then it might include some unusual activity that you wouldnt normally see, like a `mysqldump` that happened to be a one off.

A much better approach, if you have the time, would be to monitor the current machine with something like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). You can record throughput on the system's network interfaces and various metrics from MySQL using [Baron Schwartz's excellent templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/). Graphs will be created and you observe the trends from both a daily and weekly/monthly/yearly basis.